# How to remove unwanted option value from dropdown?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

```
example 1

<select id="BillTypeId" name="BillTypeId" required="" class="form-control">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="9" tax-groupid="1" data-price="1500.00" data-isfixed="False">LAUNDRY</option>
<option value="1064" tax-groupid="1" data-price="0.00" data-isfixed="False">DEBIT</option>
<option value="1065" tax-groupid="1" data-price="0.00" data-isfixed="False">CREDIT</option>
</select>
```

Let's suppose I have a dropdown with dynamic `option` values.

I have a `function` to retrieve these value from controller.

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/cash/bill/PostingBillTypeCombo',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                name: "BillTypeId",
                required: true,
                currencyId: selectedCurrencyId
            },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                if (data.op == "DEBIT" || data.op== "CREDIT")
                {
                $('#PostingBillTypeComboContainer').html("");
                $('#PostingBillTypeComboContainer').html(data);
                }

            },
        });
```

In my dropdown it has 3 values -credit , debit and laundry.

Within the `function (data)`  I use the data.op to check whether its debit or credit `if (data.op == "DEBIT" || data.op== "CREDIT")`
**(check example 1)** if it contain those names remove the rest of the option values eg:LAUNDRY and only show the debit and credit values in the dropdown.

I'm new to this please help me sorry for my poor English

Comment: Does your `data` contains the ids of each `op`? Or juste the name as a string?

Comment: please include the response from your controller

Comment: if you do console.log(data) inside if loop, what does it log?

Comment: `if (data.op...` will *not* be compatible with `$(..).html(data)`

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy It gets only the values for eg- DEBIT,CREDIT,AND LAUNDRY and then it creates a dynamic option values for them

Comment: @Wfee that's not what your code is doing...

Comment: better include sample response.

Comment: Edit your post and add more information please.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this :

```
if (data.op == "DEBIT") {
  $("#BillTypeId option:not(:contains('DEBIT'))").hide();
} else if (data.op == "CREDIT") {
  $("#BillTypeId option:not(:contains('CREDIT'))").hide();
}
```

```js
$("#BillTypeId option:not(:contains('DEBIT'))").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<select id="BillTypeId">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="9">LAUNDRY</option>
  <option value="1064">DEBIT</option>
  <option value="1065">CREDIT</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's do it with CSS:

```
.debit-credit option:not(.debit-credit) {
    display: none;
}
```

Let's apply this on the structure:

```
<select id="BillTypeId" name="BillTypeId" required="" class="form-control">
<option class="debit-credit" value=""></option>
<option value="9" tax-groupid="1" data-price="1500.00" data-isfixed="False">LAUNDRY</option>
<option class="debit-credit" value="1064" tax-groupid="1" data-price="0.00" data-isfixed="False">DEBIT</option>
<option class="debit-credit" value="1065" tax-groupid="1" data-price="0.00" data-isfixed="False">CREDIT</option>
</select>
```

Then you add `debit-credit` class to `BillTypeId` if you want to hide `LAUNDRY` and remove that class if you want to show it:

```
$.ajax({
            url: '/cash/bill/PostingBillTypeCombo',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                name: "BillTypeId",
                required: true,
                currencyId: selectedCurrencyId
            },
            method: 'POST',
            success: function (data) {
                debugger;
                if (data.op == "DEBIT" || data.op== "CREDIT")
                {
                $('#PostingBillTypeComboContainer').html("");
                $('#PostingBillTypeComboContainer').html(data);
                $('#BillTypeId').addClass("debit-credit");
                } else {
                $('#BillTypeId').removeClass("debit-credit");
                }

            },
        });
```

Here's a proof of concept: https://jsfiddle.net/hz6vqnbj/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#BillTypeId option[value=1064]").hide();
```

if you know which one to hide then use this code to hide the corresponding option by passing its value.